# c program to group students marks

Tags: c

Help, I can't seem to identify the problem in my code below.

Here's what I am trying to do: Input a list of marks. Input ends with 0 (0 itself is not someone's mark). Output the number of students who scored 
1) greater than or equal to 85; 
2) between 60 and 84; 
3) strictly less than 60.

Here's my code:

```
#include stdio.h

int main() {
    int mark;
    int morethan85 = 0, between60and84 = 0, lessthan60 = 0;

    for (true) {
        scanf("%d", &mark);
        if (mark != 0) {
            if (mark >= 85)
                morethan85 = morethan85 + 1;
            else if (mark < 85 && mark >= 60)
                between60and84 = between60and84 + 1;
            else
                lessthan60 = lessthan60 + 1;
        } else
            break;
    }

    printf(">=85:%d, morethan85");
    printf("60-84:%d, between60and84");
    printf("<60:%d, lessthan60");

}
```

Comment: What problem exactly are you having with your code?

Comment: I am having problem with the 'for (true)' its been underlined in my editor

Comment: @user1582136 the keyword `true` is in C++, but not in C. "True" in C is represented by any non-zero value, and "false" in C is represented by 0.

Comment: @sidran32, since 13 years `true` is in C also, if you include `<stdbool.h>

Comment: @user1582136, so the compiler tells you exaxtly where the problem spot is. Did you open a book or did you look on the web to find the appropriate syntax for C programs?

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, however it still is not a *keyword*, but a macro, pointing to non-zero for true, and zero for false. So my statement still stands. :)

Comment: It is defined as macro by the specification of the language, thus is part of that language in the same way as is `INT_MAX`, `offsetof` or whatever the C language defines.

Comment: @JensGustedt Point. But, macros and keywords are still different things (to the lexer). However, this is beyond the scope of the original question, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.. I am just learning the language so don't know much of the advanced stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoah. Lots of stuff to comment here.

1. First of all, "true" is not valid C. You can define a macro or constant named TRUE and set it to "1" - or simply use 1.
2. If you are looping through something until it breaks, use while() and not for().
3. Finally, the reason your code isn't working is because you have you have added the quote symbol after the name of your variables in your printf() functions.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int mark;
    int morethan85 = 0;
    int between60and84 = 0;
    int lessthan60 = 0;

    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &mark);
        if (mark != 0) {
            if (mark >= 85)
                morethan85 ++;
            else if (mark < 85 && mark >= 60)
                between60and84 ++;
            else
                lessthan60 ++;
        } else
            break;
    }

    printf(">=85:%d\n", morethan85);
    printf("60-84:%d\n", between60and84);
    printf("<60:%d\n", lessthan60);

}
```

Comment: Good, though I wouldn't have replaced `+ 1` with post-increment operators. Both work in this case, but the pre/post-increment operators have other behaviors that change how right-hand-expressions evaluate, and in this case, adds unnecessary complexity to the answer. When teaching, you don't want to make lots of little extra, unrelated changes, no matter how minor, so you don't overwhelm the one asking the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responce.. I am new to the language

Comment: `true` *is* valid C since C99.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> printf(">=85:%d, morethan85");
>                            ^
> ```

You're printing plain strings. Try this instead:

```
printf(">=85:%d", morethan85);
               ^
```

---

Also, strictly speaking, passing fewer arguments than required by the format string is undefined behavior.

Comment: As I was typing my answer, you responded with the same thing. :P +1